# Python Multiprocessing Pool passing function arguments

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I've got 4 nested loops, where I loop though lists of lists, and a function where I pass some arguments I get from the function, specifically:

```
def method(var1, var2 ....., var 16):
  #computation 

pool = Pool()

for values1 in list_of_values1:
  #assign 4 variables from the list 
  for values2 in list_of_values2:
    #assign 4 variables from list 
    for values3 in list_of_values3:
      #assign 4 variables from  list 
      for values4 in list_of_values4:
        #assign 4 variables from list
        method(var1, ..., var16)
```

I have tried using the

> pool.map(method, [var1,..., var16])
>   in order to paralelize the whole process but it throws an error saying "method() takes exactly 16 arguments, 1 given"

I have also tried to use Threads but it does not improve much.

Grateful for the help!

Cheers

Comment: can you show your attempted `pool.map` call?

Comment: pool.map(method, [var1,..., var16]) like this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Pool.map` is designed to call `method` on each value in the iterator you pass as the second argument. So in your example, it will try to do the following in parallel:

```
method(var1)
method(var2)
method(var3)
...
method(var16)
```

I think what you want to do is:

```
for values1 in list_of_values1:
  #assign 4 variables from the list 
  for values2 in list_of_values2:
    #assign 4 variables from list 
    for values3 in list_of_values3:
      #assign 4 variables from  list 
      for values4 in list_of_values4:
        #assign 4 variables from list
        pool.apply_async(method, (var1, ..., var16))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

This is just calling `method` with the 16 arguments it expects, but doing it in a background process.

It's also possible you can do something a little nicer than the multiple nested for loops, by using itertools to build a list of (var1, ..., var16) tuples, which could then be passed to `pool.map`. But it depends on what `#assign 4 variables from list*` actually does.

Comment: If it tries to do                                                method(var1)
method(var2)
method(var3)
...
method(var16) I'm not really sure how that helps, because I need all of the values when I make the function call. Maybe I am not understanding this properly

Comment: Exactly. I was trying to explain why `pool.map` the way you're using it isn't helpful. The code example I included that uses `pool.apply_async` does do the right thing, though.

Comment: Right, cheers, I'll try it off now :) I need the for loops. **It's how the algorithm works